# Trying to implement XGBoost into my Artificial Neural Network

Tags: python, neural-network

I'm completely unaware as to why i'm receiving this error. I am trying to implement XGBoost but it returns with error "ValueError: For a sparse output, all columns should be a numeric or convertible to a numeric." Even after i've One Hot Encoded my categorical data. If anyone knows what is causing this and a possible solution i'd greatly appreciate it. Here is my code written in Python:

```
# Artificial Neural Networks - With XGBoost

# PRE PROCESS

# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('Churn_Modelling.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 3:13].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 13].values

# Encoding Categorical Data
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

ct = ColumnTransformer([('encoder', OneHotEncoder(), [1, 2])],
                     remainder = 'passthrough')
X = np.array(ct.fit_transform(X), dtype = np.float)


# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state = 0)

# Fitting XGBoost to the training set
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
classifier = XGBClassifier()
classifier.fit(x_train, y_train)

# Predicting the Test set Results
y_pred = classifier.predict(x_test)

# Making the Confusion Matrix
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)

# Applying k-Fold Cross Validation
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
accuracies = cross_val_score(estimator = classifier, X = X_train, y = y_train, cv = 10)
accuracies.mean()
accuracies.std()
```

Comment: It would be better if you tell the line number where the error happened.

Comment: The error is caused by the line where I attempt to import xgboost

Comment: Are you sure, all values are numeric?